# Can't add function to expression evaluator in jcl

Tags: expression, evaluation

I need your help regarding JCL.
i am using the example "examples\common\exprEval" provided by Jcl which adds some functions to the Tevaluator. but i cant add more functions. When i do so i get the following:
dcc32 Error] ExprEvalExampleLogic.pas(57): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'AddFunc' that can be called with these arguments.

Comment: Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The JCL tag is for Mainframe JCL (Job Control Language), I will remove the tag

Comment: No not at all . It is about jedi components library.